# Running ant as administrator...through Eclipse

Tags: java, windows-7, ant, apache

I just inherited a project that uses Tomcat to serve JSPs, but Apache httpd to server Javascript...

The Ant build for this project creates and deletes directories inside the `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\` directory, which is an "admin" directory in Windows 7 land.

When I try to run this Ant build inside of Eclipse, the build fails because it is unable to create the necessary directories because its getting permission/access denied errors.

Is there any way to configure Ant (run arguments, etc.) to run as administrator from inside Eclipse? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just run Eclipse as Administrator?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this Adam? If so, can you please post? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Even if this is an old question...I recently had a similar authorization problem with Win10 and Ant v.1.10.1 inside Eclipse Oxygen (4.7.1). I was trying to control a Windows Service (Tomcat) from an Ant-task but got: 
    stopTomcat:
     [exec] System error 5 has occurred.
     [exec] Access is denied.
     [exec] Result: 2
    startTomcat:
     [echo] Start Tomcat
     [exec] System error 5 has occurred.
     [exec] Access is denied.
     [exec] Result: 2

Starting/running Eclipse as administrator made all the difference :-)